# Как получить ключ массива для значения с определенным количеством символов

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите как можно получить ключ массива у которого значение, например равно 5 символов?
Уточнение: нужно получить ключ первого найденного элемента в массиве

Answer (score 1):

Можно выбрать такие элементы из массива при помощи функции array_filter

```
$res = array_filter($arr, function($k) { return strlen($k) == 5; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Comment: по сути нужно чтобы возвращало первый найденный

Comment: @IZrchnsk воспользуйтесь после этого функцией `reset($res)`, она вернёт первый элемент.

Comment: Reset array_shift [0] current

Comment: Возможно как то еще это сделать , другим способом?

Comment: И этот пример не работает - Notice: Undefined variable: k in

Comment: Поменяйте k на х или наоборот, я ошибся

Answer (score 1):

простой перебор массива вам в помощь

```
function x($arr){
    foreach($arr as $k => $v){
        if(strlen($v) == 5) return $k;
    } 
    return null;
}
```